# Select different CSS files based on IE version in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm currently using HTML conditional statements to select a CSS file based on IE version. How do I do this on the server side instead.

```
<!--[if IE 6]> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/ie6.css" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/ie7.css" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/ie8.css" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Like That.., i have code from html and rewrite in aspx

Comment: Tanks balexandre for edited my question..

Comment: @YusanSusandi in the [faq's](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) you find out how to use the markup correctly, as well when you are writing, you can simple open the orange `?` sign to open up a simple dialog with the markup formating that you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine the browser type from the HTTP request:

```
System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = Request.Browser
```

Then render the page accordingly:

```
<% if (browser.Browser == "IE" && browser.MajorVersion == 6) { %>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/ie6.css" media="screen" />
<% } else if (browser.Browser == "IE" && browser.MajorVersion == 7) { %>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/ie7.css" media="screen" />
<% } else if (browser.Browser == "IE" && browser.MajorVersion == 8) { %>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/ie8.css" media="screen" />
<% } %>
```

I believe you have to set the `runat="server"` attribute within the `<head>` element of the page for this to work.

This isn't a very good way of doing it though. A better way would be to do it client-side using either JavaScript or the method used in the question.

Comment: If a client is spoofing their userAgent, they deserve any rendering issues the have. :P

Answer (score 0):

- What's your directory structure?
- What ASP.NET Framework are you using, Webforms, MVC?

The only thing that come up to my mind is the CSS Path that you are using, in MVC for example, the default behavior you should write `/Content/Css/ie6.css` for example.

A good idea is always use the backslash sign `/` that will point to the website root and append the folder in the path from there.

Every thing else works well in ASP.NET, **just remember** that the only difference is that a plain HTML page does not need any server to run, so it picks everything where you open the file in your browser, an a PHP / ASP.NET need a Server to run into, so you need to respect the Server Paths.

*By the way*, I would recommend [**Html5 boilerplate**](http://html5boilerplate.com/) if you are starting a new website...

Comment: Between "<!--" and "-->" in aspx read as comentar so not will execution. How to write in aspx? that code i'm put in tag <head> ... </head>

Comment: No, that's your editor highlighting, the code will run as is and will output exactly what it needs. Just try yourself with a simple CSS rule only, for example `body { background-color: red; }` and change the color in the other 3 files (`ie7.css`, `ie8.css` and the `.html` file - making sure that the `red` background is in `ie6.css`)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should stick with your current solution but if you need to do it server side you could always check the user agent and then register the stylesheet.

Something like this;

```
Dim userAgent As String = Request.UserAgent

If (userAgent.IndexOf("MSIE 6.0") > -1) Then

  HtmlLink css = new HtmlLink();
  css.Href = "css/ie6.css";
  css.Attributes["rel"] = "stylesheet";
  css.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
  css.Attributes["media"] = "all";
  Page.Header.Controls.Add(css);

End If
```

Read more about the [HttpRequest.UserAgent Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.useragent.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<link runat="server" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
   ie:href="style/ie6.css" ie7:href="style/ie7.css" ie8:href="style/ie8.css"
   ie9:href="style/ie8.css" ie0plus:"style/ie8.css"
   media="screen" />
```

The property modifiers like "ie:" match the furthest element down the browser tree they can, so "ie" alone will match all IE browsers, but if it's IE7, then "ie7" will match instead. I don't think there's a browser pattern for IE6, which is why you need the keys for ie9 and ie10plus; since they are further down the tree, they will match instead of just "ie".

The .NET browser pattern files are located in:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\Browsers
```

You can also add your own pattern files if you want (don't edit the existing ones). After adding one, run:

```
aspnet_regbrowsers -i
```

Answer (score 0):

Note re. accepted answer (adding code to `<head>`):

This will cause an error if `<head>` is set as `runat="server"` and you (or any other code) attempts to alter the HEAD's `.Controls` collection.

The AJAX Control Toolkit does this in some situations.

Answer (score -1):

not sure how to do it using aspx, but there are many ways to do it using [JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp).